# Understanding javascript object creation and prototype

Tags: javascript

Consider the following:

Are the following code piece equivalient ?

```
var foo = Class.create();
foo.prototype = {
    initialize : function() {};
    sayHello : function() {};
}
```

and

```
    var foo = Class.create();
    foo.prototype = {
        initialize : function() {};
    } 
   foo.prototype.sayHello : function() {};
```

Secondly, which one to prefer other the other ? `when and why` ?

Comment: ok whats the right thing ?

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help you understand what prototype does and what a constructor function or initializer does.http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both wrong, they should be

```
var foo = new Object();
foo.prototype = {
  initialize : function() {},
  sayHello : function() {}
}
```

and

```
var foo = new Object();
foo.prototype = {
    initialize : function() {}
} 
foo.prototype.sayHello = function() {};
```

and yes they're the same

I prefer the first way for initialize because is more clear

Comment: @JavaDeveloper class is not a javascript object, maybe it's from any framework

Comment: var Person = Class.create();
Person.prototype = {
  initialize: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  },
  say: function(message) {
    return this.name + ': ' + message;
  }
};

Comment: @JavaDeveloper "In early versions of Prototype, the framework came with basic support for class creation", it's a framework, Class is not a built-in object of javascript

Comment: @JavaDeveloper i don't know prototype framework so i guess Class.create() is fine with it, i prefer code in pure javascript or with jquery personally; with jquery for example you can add functions directly to the jQuery object prototype